# estoy limitando el largo de un texto (labels) en ChartJs, pero no lo hace de forma correcta

Tags: chart.js

Estoy usando [ChartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) para generar unos gráficos, estoy haciendo un `type: "horizontalBar"`

El problema que tengo es el siguiente:

Estoy obteniendo unos "nombres" que los paso como `labels`.

Cuando ingresé un nombre largo para ver como era el comportamiento, me di cuenta que el gráfico se hacia mas estrecho de ancho, entonces busque una forma de que el texto tenga algo tipo `max-width` de `css`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

encontré [esta pregunta](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2626) donde buscan hacer lo que quiero hacer yo,

donde en una de las repuestas recomiendan usar:

```
 afterFit : función ( scaleInstance )  { 
    scaleInstance . ancho  =  100 ;  // establece el ancho en px 
 }
```

y lo agregue a mi código, funciono pero..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me esta "cortando" el texto de una forma no adecuada, entonces como puedo corregir eso?

---

MI CÓDIGO DEL GRÁFICO:

```
var myChart = new Chart(grafico_a, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
      labels: response.map(item => item.nombres),   //aquí es donde obtiene los nombres.
     
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Años',
        backgroundColor: colorido,  //array con colores aleatorios
        data:  response.map(item => item.anios), //años de objeto
      }
    ],
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            display: false,
            drawBorder: false
          },
          ticks: {
            fontColor: "#000000",
            stepSize: 1,
            min: 0,
          },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            afterFit : función ( scaleInstance )  { 
               scaleInstance . ancho  =  200;
            } 
          ticks: {
            fontColor: "#000000",
            display: true,
          },
          gridLines: {
            color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
            zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
            drawBorder: false,
            borderDash: [2],
            zeroLineBorderDash: [2],
          },
        }],
      },
    }
  });
```